# C# stream out of order when using TCP send/receive

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I was creating a small client/server application when I encountered something that seemed to be a mixup in the TCP streem, so I wrote a small test application

The server just creates a TCP socket and sends an incrementing counter

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
socket.Listen(10);

Socket clientSocket = socket.Accept();

byte test = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (clientSocket.Send(new byte[] { test }, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None) == 1)
    {
        test++;
    }
}
```

As this is a TCP stream I would expect a stream at the client that just goes from 0 to 255 and so on.

Using the following at the client:

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7777);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
byte last = 255;
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != (byte)(last+1))
        {
            //problem here
        }
        last = buffer[i];
    }
}
```

The if condition should never return true but it does. After I analyzed the stream at the client it showed that quite often the buffer contains sequences like 000 001 002 003 004 005 006 102 103 104 105.

What am I missing here? I always thought TCP would ensure in order delivery at the TCP level.

**Update**: Thorarin pointed to the correct solution. Zone Alarm was messing around with the stream (or probably with the packets). I am going to uninstall this software.

Comment: Are the numbers always incrementing with gaps or are they actually out of order? Is it possible that some packets are timing out somewhere in that loop and that you are only picking up certain packets from the stream?

Comment: Numbers are incrementing but have huge gaps. There are no exceptions thrown and I hoped that .net takes care of the packet (IP) level. Using Wireshark it turns out that the gaps are always at the end of a packet. But shouldn't TCP ensure the delivery of the data? I am not yet sure if there is data missing or just in the wrong order.

Comment: how are you checking Wireshark? I was under the impression that Wireshark was unable to capture the loopback interface.

Comment: @Thorarin You can use the internal IP (192.168.1.112) and add a route to route everything to that ip over the gateway (your router). Yes this is kind of stupid but then you have the traffic on your NIC and Wireshark can capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP [does guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission) in order delivery. My guess would be something is going wrong with your receive buffer. Maybe you are connecting twice and using the same buffer?

I've tried to reproduce your problem, but I cannot. I'm not sure what `clientSocketState` is referring to, so I used a regular byte array for the buffer. Instead of `BeginAccept` I lazily used `Accept`, but no other changes were made.

Something else must be going on that you're not telling us :-)

**Update**: considering everything, I'm starting to believe that some firewall or anti-virus software is messing things up for you.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I was experimenting if it has something to do with sync/async and made some mixup when posting the code. I cleaned it up and edited my question.

There is only one connection and one buffer.

Comment: @Peter: I've modified my code to reflect your update, but the error still isn't surfacing here, nor can I think of a legitimate reason why it would occur on a different system. Some kind of firewall/anti-virus that's messing up?

Comment: argh, why didn't I think of that :) You are right. It turns out ZoneAlarm is messing around with the packets! I am not sure why this happens but for sure I am going to uninstall this software now. Thx :)